# Parse JSON (in nested key value) to CSV

Tags: json, parsing, export-to-csv, python-3.7

I have json file named test.json .It contains

```
{
    "rl": {
        "entries": [
            {
                "query_value": {
                    "value": "0dedc344b2658a1328de3578"
                },
                "status": "KNOWN"
            },
            {
                "query_value": {
                    "value": "065d451e42bc31363cbe6c"
                },
                "status": "KNOWN"
            },
            {
                "query_value": {
                    "value": "00fb1e5be9df8338833c1c"
                },
                "status": "UNKNOWN"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Need to parse it to CSV , 
In CSV , output should be

```
value                          status
0dedc344b2658a1328de3578       KNOWN
065d451e42bc31363cbe6c         KNOWN
00fb1e5be9df8338833c1c         UNKNOWN
```

Already i have checked with loading into jsondump, but can't able to retrieve the property field "value" and "status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
import json
js_st = """[your json string above]"""
dat = json.loads(js_st)
rows = []
targets = dat['rl']['entries']
for target in targets:
    rows.extend([[target['query_value']['value'],target['status']]])
```

That would give you rows of target data which you can write to a csv file using standard python `writer.writerows(rows)`.